# How to find $\text {Ker} (T)$ when you do not have a matrix $A$ that represents the transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

Usually finding $\ker(T)$ with a matrix that represents the transformation is relatively straightforward. You solve for $Ax = 0$ by using gauss-jordan.

But when you do not have a matrix that represents the transformation **(it's not provided)**, solving $Ax = 0$ is rather confusing and less straightforward. I want to know if there is a general pattern or guidelines in solving this types of problems.

Examples:

$1)$ $T: \Bbb M_{2 \times 2} \longrightarrow P_2[x]$ defined by $$T\left [\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c  & d \end{pmatrix}\right ] \mapsto (a+b) + (b+c)x + (c+d)x^2.$$

$2)$ $T: P_2[t] \longrightarrow \Bbb M_{2 \times 2}$ defined by $$p(t) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} p(0) & p'(0) \\ p'(0) & p''(0) \end{pmatrix}.$$

***I am not asking how to solve these to examples, I am asking what are the guidelines (Steps) to solve problems of the same genre.***

If you could also point me two a ressource where I could find more problems of this type so I can practice myself; I would be really grateful.

Comment: For the first problem $ker (T) = \left \{\begin{pmatrix} a & -a \\ a & -a \end{pmatrix} \in \Bbb M_{2 \times 2} (\Bbb R) : a \in \Bbb R \right \}.$

Answer (score 2):

The first comes down to finding all matrices $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}$ such that its $T$-value is the $0$-polynomial $0+0\cdot x+0\cdot x^2$, i.e. $a+b=0$ and $b+c=0$ and $c+d=0$. This is just a standard linear system of 3 equations in $4$ variables. It consists of all matrices of the form (using $d$ as a free variable) $\begin{pmatrix}-t & t \\ -t & t\end{pmatrix}, t \in \mathbb{R}$.

The last looks for all polynomials $p(t)$ of at most degree $2$ such that $p(0)=0=p'(0)=p''(0)$ and setting $p(t)=a+bt + ct^2$, so $p'(t)=b+2ct$, $p''(t)=2c$ these conditions yield $2c=0$ so $c=0$, then using the $p'(0)=0$ we get $b=0$ and finally $p(0)=0$ gives $a=0$, so only the $0$-polynomial lies in the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem $$ker (T) = \left \{\begin{pmatrix} a & -a \\ a & -a \end{pmatrix} \in \Bbb M_{2 \times 2} (\Bbb R) : a \in \Bbb R \right \}$$ and for the second problem $ker(T)$ contains all the polynomials of which has no term upto $x^2.$  But the degree of each polynomial in $\Bbb P_2[t]$ is at most $2.$ So for the second problem $ker (T) = \{0 \}.$

Comment: $\ker(T)$ does not contain all polynomials of degree$\ge3$

Comment: Because constant coefficient, coefficient of $x$ and coefficient of $x^2$ are all zero by the condition that $p(0)=p'(0)=p''(0) =0.$

Comment: $x^3+x$ is also a polynomial of degree $3$ but doesn't lie in the kernel. Perhaps you meant all polynomials with the lowest exponent of $x\ge3$?

Comment: But the problem is that there is no polynomial in $\Bbb P_2[t]$ of degree greater or equal to $3.$ So the only polynomial satisfying the result is the zero polynomial.

Comment: Oh! Yeah. Sorry. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

You *always* have matrices representing the linear map. Let's do the first one.

Consider the basis
$$
E_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\quad
E_2=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\quad
E_3=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix},
\quad
E_4=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
of the domain and the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ of the codomain.

Then the matrix of $T$ with respect to these bases is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the RREF is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The null space of this matrix has a basis consisting of the single vector
$$
\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
so that the matrix this is the coordinate vector of, namely
$$
-E_1+E_2-E_3+E_4=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
forms a basis of the kernel of $T$.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, fall back on basic definitions: the kernel of a linear transformation is the set of vectors in its domain that get mapped to $0$.

So, for the first problem, you’re looking for $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$ such that $(a+b)+(b+c)x+(c+d)x^2=0$ for all $x$. This means that all of the coefficients of this polynomial must vanish, which gives you a system of linear equations to solve for $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

In the same vein, for the second problem, you’re looking for polynomials $p(t)=a+bt+ct^2$ such that $p(0)=p'(0)=p''(0)=0$. Each of these conditions generates a rather simple linear equation in $a$, $b$ and $c$.